# Allowing only one async operation at a time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a site and one particular operation triggers a long, server-side process to run. This operation can't be run twice at the same time, so I need to implement some sort of protection. It also can't be made synchronous, because the server needs to continue responding to other requests while it runs.

To that end I've constructed this small concept test, using `sleep 5` as a substitute for my actual long-running process (requires *express* and *child-process-promise*, runs on a system with a `sleep` command but substitute whatever for Windows):

```
var site = require("express")();
var exec = require("child-process-promise").exec;

var busy = false;

site.get("/test", function (req, res) {
    if (busy) {
        res.json({status:"busy"});
    } else {
        busy = true; // <-- set busy before we start
        exec("sleep 5").then(function () {
            res.json({status:"ok"});    
        }).catch(function (err) {
            res.json({status:err.message});
        }).then(function () {
            busy = false; // <-- finally: clear busy
        });
    }
});

site.listen(8082);
```

The intention of this is when "/test" is requested it triggers a long operation, and if "/test" is requested again while it is running, it replies with "busy" and does nothing.

My question is, is this implementation safe and correct? It appears to work in my cursory tests but it's suspiciously simple. Is this the proper way to essentially implement a mutex + a "try-lock" operation, or is there some more appropriate Node.js construct? Coming from languages where I'm used to standard multithreading practices, I'm not *quite* comfortable with Node's single-threaded-but-asynchronous nature yet.

Comment: You're fine - Javascript code can't run concurrently with other JS code in Node, so nothing will change the busy flag out from under you. No need for multithreaded-styled monitors or critical sections.

Comment: So to be clear, the long running process is executed as a child process of the server, it's not run by the server (Node.js) itself?

Comment: @FelixKling I'm not *quite* sure I understand the question so here's a bunch of random statements: It's executed with exec, not spawn - that is I don't need to read its output or track its progress as it runs, the process just does a bunch of stuff that takes a while then ends and I only care about the end result. Also it's not run automatically or at intervals, it's triggered directly by an end-user via an HTTP request, at which point I exec it, and return the status to the end-user. Does any of that answer your question? I can explain my actual use-case too if you think it matters.

Comment: Yep. I just wanted to know whether you are starting a new process or if the expensive computation is done by Node.js itself. If it was the latter, then the server couldn't even accept new client requests since it would be busy with the expensive computation. But if you start a child process then its fine.

Comment: This code would actually work, but what if your server dies or you need to add another one (for failover)? I'd think about a better way of implementing this, using a job processing mechanism

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin This is good for now, but that's a good point. I found a neat looking [gearman client for Node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gearman); maybe I'll play with that for a while. I've never used gearman before so it will take some more experimenting to get it working like I want, but looks promising (despite the disappointingly incomplete documentation).

Comment: Hey @ChrisTavares do you want to post that as an answer?

Comment: @JasonC Ok, just did.

Comment: Not sure if your promises support it, but you should change the last `.then` to `.finally` so that the `busy` always gets cleared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're fine - Javascript code can't run concurrently with other JS code in Node.  Nothing will change the busy flag out from under you. No need for multithreaded-styled monitors or critical sections.