# What is the difference between then and finally in a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I see the docs for Bluebird's [`finally`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html) but I still don't quite understand the difference vs. `then`.

To be clear: I know exactly why `then` gets called after a `catch`. I *want* it to be called after a catch. That's the intent. My question is: If I *want* code to always be executed regardless of the promise state, what's the difference between `then` vs `finally` for that?

I built this test:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");

function test1 () {
    console.log("RESOLVE + THEN + CATCH + THEN");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve())
       .then(() => console.log("then"))
       .catch(err => console.log("error:", err.message))
       .then(() => console.log("end"));
}

function test2 () {
    console.log("REJECT + THEN + CATCH + THEN");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(new Error("rejected")))
       .then(() => console.log("then"))
       .catch(err => console.log("error:", err.message))
       .then(() => console.log("end"));
}

function test3 () {
    console.log("RESOLVE + THEN + CATCH + FINALLY");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve())
       .then(() => console.log("then"))
       .catch(err => console.log("error:", err.message))
       .finally(() => console.log("end"));
}

function test4 () {
    console.log("REJECT + THEN + CATCH + FINALLY");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(new Error("rejected")))
       .then(() => console.log("then"))
       .catch(err => console.log("error:", err.message))
       .finally(() => console.log("end"));
}

// run tests "sequentially" so console output doesn't get blended
setTimeout(test1, 500);
setTimeout(test2, 1000);
setTimeout(test3, 1500);
setTimeout(test4, 2000);
```

This tests four cases:

1. `.then(...).catch(...).then(...)` with a resolved promise.
2. `.then(...).catch(...).then(...)` with a rejected promise.
3. `.then(...).catch(...).finally(...)` with a resolved promise.
4. `.then(...).catch(...).finally(...)` with a rejected promise.

The results I see are cases 1+2 behaves identically to 3+4: The last bit (`then` or `finally` depending on test) executes no matter what happens before it, as intended. The output of that program is:

```
RESOLVE + THEN + CATCH + THEN
then
end
REJECT + THEN + CATCH + THEN
error: rejected
end
RESOLVE + THEN + CATCH + FINALLY
then
end
REJECT + THEN + CATCH + FINALLY
error: rejected
end
```

Now, the reason I'm asking is because I saw a [comment on this other question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108293/allowing-only-one-async-operation-at-a-time?noredirect=1#comment69462006_41108293):

> Not sure if your promises support it, but you should change the last `.then` to `.finally` so that the `busy` always gets cleared.

From my very limited knowledge of `then`, and the tests above, it seems like `then` is sufficient. But after that comment I'm questioning myself and the safety of using `then` to execute "finally" code.

So my question is: What's the difference between `then` and `finally`? They *look* like they behave the same, but when would I need to use `finally` instead of `then`?

Comment: your question seems to boil down to why does .then get called on your rejected promise, right? reading the docs for .catch would answer that.

Comment: @KevinB No, not at all. I know exactly why `then` gets called after a `catch`. I *want* it to be called after a catch. I'm asking: If I *want* code to always be executed regardless of the promise state, what's the difference between `then` vs `finally` for that?

Comment: @KevinB You might be missing the point, or my question might be so obvious that it's not coming across right. I'm not sure. Let me ask another way: Does [this comment have any merit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108293/allowing-only-one-async-operation-at-a-time?noredirect=1#comment69462006_41108293)?

Comment: I think it does, in that it guarentees that regardless of whether or not you catch the error, it will still call the finally. But in your code you always catch it, so there's no difference.

Comment: @KevinB But doesn't `then` after `catch` give the exact same guarantee? In my test it does. So then the question is: What's the difference? Why would I use `finally` instead of `then`, after a `catch`?

Comment: well, it does, ***if it's after a catch***. that's my point.

Comment: @KevinB So why ever use `finally`? Why not just always use `then`? That means that comment *doesn't* have merit and I'm fine with `then` in that example, and *don't* have to change to `finally`, right?

Comment: It's for cases where the promise could either be resolved or rejected. In your case it's always resolved, so there's no difference.

Comment: @KevinB Not in test2 and test4. Those are both rejected. And the behavior is the same in both of those - i.e. `then` and `finally` show no difference in all cases. But there must be a difference, because otherwise `finally` wouldn't be a thing that exists -- I just don't know what that difference is. Here's a different way to phrase it: If I replaced all `finally`s in the world with `then`s, would anything change?

Comment: the .catch makes it a resolved promise..

Comment: eh, i'm not sure i get that last comment. ultimately, in both cases, resolved and rejected, then and finally, you end with a resolved promise due to the .catch.  If the .catch wasn't there, test 2 wouldn't log `end` and test 4 would. 1 and 3 would as well, of course.

Comment: All right, I guess I still don't understand. It seems to me like if I `s/finally/then/g` in any program, it's behavior wouldn't change at all. Is `finally` just a synonym for `then`?

Comment: @JasonC, 1st: sometimes you don't want to catch errors at the place they arise, but in the Code that uses this function; so you don't catch them. In that case you can't substitute `then()` and `finally()`. Sometimes you have to clean sth. up wether there was an Error or not. (nulling References clearing timeouts, ... stuff like that) That's where you use `finally()`. 2nd: The function you pass to `catch()` could also throw, then you would have a rejected Promise and the following `then()` would not be called.

Comment: @Thomas Ah, awesome. I just posted a self-answer with your #2, figured it out at the same time. But didn't think of your #1 (so a `finally` *before* a `catch` will still execute on an error, didn't know that). Makes a lot of sense. You're welcome to post it as an answer, it's more complete than mine. Right now I'm having an internal struggle about having this question answered vs. deleting it in shame.

Comment: well, now you can't delete it. problem solved!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First difference: Sometimes you don't want to catch errors at the place they arise, but in the code that uses this function, so you don't catch them. In that case you can't substitute `then()` and `finally()`.

Sometimes you have to clean something up whether there was an error or not (nulling references, clearing timeouts ... stuff like that).  That's where you use `finally()`.

Second difference: The function you pass to `catch()` could also throw, then you would have a rejected Promise and the following `then()` would not be called.

> (so a finally before a catch will still execute on an error, didn't know that)

Yeah, that's the point of `finally()`. It will be executed under any circumstance without changing the resolved value.

You might want to read/google a bit about `try {} finally {}`, without catch.

Answer (score 9):

`.then` and `.finally` are not the same.

`.then` is the main promise primitive. It's what is defined, thoroughly, in the [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/) and all promise libraries will implement it.

A Bluebird [`.finally`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html) handler will "be called regardless of the promise's fate". So an unhandled exception still triggers a `.finally`.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(false))
  .finally(a => console.log('finally', a))
// finally undefined
// Unhandled rejection false

new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(false))
  .then(a => console.log('then', a))
// Unhandled rejection false
```

`.finally` won't change the resolved value of the promise and doesn't receive the result of the promise chain.

```
new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(false))
  .catch(e => {
    console.log(e)
    return 2
  })
  .finally(a => {
    console.log('finally', a)
    return 1
  })
  .then(res => console.log('res', res))
// finally undefined
// res 2
```

The methods look similar in your test cases as the tests catch all errors and you are only using promises for flow control, not relying on the values being resolve/rejected along the promise chain.

Comment: Incidentally, if anybody else is reading this, now that I've got these concepts down I've found a few other things, and `.tap()` is one: `tap` is sort of like halfway between `then` and `finally`: Like `then`, it's not called on rejection, but like `finally` it doesn't change the result and so the previous result "skips" over it. Neat.

Answer (score 7):

All right, after some chatting and a lot of help from KevinB, I figured out at least one difference. Consider the following two new tests:

```
function test5 () {
    console.log("REJECT + THEN + CATCH/THROW + THEN");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(new Error("rejected")))
       .then(() => console.log("then"))
       .catch(function(err) { throw new Error("error in catch"); })
       .then(() => console.log("end"));
}

function test6 () {
    console.log("REJECT + THEN + CATCH/THROW + FINALLY");
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject(new Error("rejected")))
       .then(() => console.log("then"))
       .catch(function(err) { throw new Error("error in catch"); })
       .finally(() => console.log("end"));
}
```

In these the promise is rejected, but an error is thrown from `catch`.

The promise ends up ultimately rejected in both cases but for the `finally` case the `finally` is still executed, the `then` is not.

So *that's* the difference. They're *almost* the same with the sole exception that when an error is thrown from the *`catch`* handler, `finally` executes, and `then` does not.

This means the comment I quoted also does have merit: If in my error handler another error occurred, a `then` wouldn't guarantee clean-up, but a `finally` would. That's the case I was missing.

Comment: Also `.finally` doesn't affect the value resolved for a promise, whereas `.then` will.

Comment: @Matt, not if the function returns `undefined`. But you're right, `finally()` guarantees that the resolved value won't be changed.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry I don't understand your `undefined` caveat? Do you mean you don't see the effect if you return `undefined` everywhere?

Comment: @Matt, afaik every major implementation of Promises in JS doesn't alter the resolved value if the function you pass to `then()` doesn't return a value (aka `undefined`), but instead resolves to the previous value.

Comment: @Thomas Native and Bluebird will resolve `undefined` so I assume that's the spec. `new Promise(resolve => resolve(true)).then(res => console.log('res',res)).then(res => console.log('res', res))`