# Difference between finally() and then() in ES2018

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-next

Before ES2018, I used to nest an extra `then` at the end of the promise chain whenever I had to perform any clean up logic that I'd otherwise duplicate in `then` and `catch` above, e.g.

```js
new Promise(
  (res, rej) => setTimeout(() => rej({}), 1000)
).then(
  res => console.log(res)
).catch(
  err => console.error(err)
).then(
  () => console.log('Finally')
)
```

But now that `finally` was added on the `Promise` prototype, I can't see how it's different from the last `then` in the above approach. The following will produce identical output.

```js
new Promise(
  (res, rej) => setTimeout(() => rej({}), 1000)
).then(
  res => console.log(res)
).catch(
  err => console.error(err)
).finally(
  () => console.log('Finally')
)
```

Does `finally` merely serve a semantic purpose in the native Promise API?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130154/what-is-the-difference-between-then-and-finally-in-a-promise

Comment: @epascarello That one is about Bluebird

Comment: It is all basically the same thing

Comment: The differences are literally listed in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally#Description). They're not quite the same.

Comment: @Herohtar Sure, but the docs contrast it with `.then(() => {}, () => {})`. I'm talking about `.then(() => {}).catch(() => {}).then(() => {})`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `then` callback doesn't execute when the promise is rejected - and that can happen even for a promise returned by a `catch` invocation: when its callback throws or returns a rejected promise. `err => console.error(err)` is *probably* not going to do that, but you never know.

Similarly, I would recommend to [favour `.then(…, …)` over `.then(…).catch(…)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24662289/1048572) if you only want to handle errors from the original promise, not from the `then` callback. I'd write

```
promise.then(console.log, console.error).finally(() => console.log('Finally'));
```

The other [more or less obvious](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally#Description) differences are in the signature: the `finally` callback doesn't receive any arguments, and the promise that `p.finally()` returns will fulfill/reject with the same result as `p` (unless there's an exception or returned rejection in the callback).

Answer (score 1):

`finally()` executes whether the promise is fulfilled or rejected. Maybe the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally)'s example will help.

Edit: the MDN doc gives these differences from `then()`:

> The `finally()` method is very similar to calling `.then(onFinally, onFinally)` however there are couple of differences:
>
> - When creating a function inline, you can pass it once, instead of being forced to either declare it twice, or create a variable for it
> - A `finally` callback will not receive any argument, since there's no reliable means of determining if the promise was fulfilled or
>     rejected. This use case is for precisely when you do not care about
>     the rejection reason, or the fulfillment value, and so there's no need
>     to provide it.
> - Unlike `Promise.resolve(2).then(() => {}, () => {})` (which will be resolved with `undefined`), `Promise.resolve(2).finally(() => {})`
>     will be resolved with `2`.
> - Similarly, unlike `Promise.reject(3).then(() => {}, () => {})` (which will be fulfilled with `undefined`),
>     `Promise.reject(3).finally(() => {})` will be rejected with `3`.

Comment: So does the last `then` after `catch`. That's the whole point.

Comment: @Alex But you might not always use it after `catch`.

Comment: And you might not always have catch