# subscribe is not a function

Tags: asp.net, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, observable

I'm trying to get data from ASP.net core web API and access inside the ionic 3 application. Getting data from asp.net is successfully attempted. But I want to filter the retrieve data inside the ionic app. I wrote the below code to filter products by using the subscribe function.

```js
import {ProductProvider} from '../../providers/product/product';

constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private camera: Camera,
    public alertCtrl:AlertController,
    public actionsheet:ActionSheetController,
    public image:UploadProvider,
    public pro:ProductProvider) {
}

getMyproduct() {
    this.pro.getPostedProducts()
        .then(data => {
            this.products = data;
            console.log(data);

            this.id = this.sellerID.id;
            this.products.subscribe(productevents => {
                let productevent = productevents

                this.myProduct_arr = productevent.filter(event => {
                    return event.sid=this.sellerID;
                })
            })
        })
}
```

```html
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let product of myProduct_arr">
    <p> {{product.name}}</p>
    <p> {{product.brand}}</p>
    <p> {{product.price}}</p>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

but when I run it I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: _this.products.subscribe is not a function
```

can anyone say what is the reason for this?

Comment: the this.data is not an observable, where do you get the product events from? can you share what is in the data obj

Comment: I'm getting data from MongoDB . for that I'm using productProvider for getting data.   postapiUrl="http://localhost:55427";
  
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello ProductProvider Provider');
  }
  getPostedProducts(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get(this.postapiUrl+'/product').subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code snippet where you use .subscribe:

```
this.products.subscribe(productevents=>{
```

You're using subscribe on the object this.products but products isn't declared in your controller as an observable.

It looks like inside your `.then` function you are referencing the data you're intending to use...

```
this.products = data;
```

On this line you are setting this.products to the response from .getPostedProducts() function. If one depends on the response to be delivered successfully from the other, I recommend `.then` chaining with `.finally`. You can read about it in this post:

[What is the difference between then and finally in a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41130154/what-is-the-difference-between-then-and-finally-in-a-promise)